# Be able to give 4 latitude/longitude points and see if the 5th is within the specified region

Tags: google-maps

I have an interesting problem where I want to see if a pair of Latitude/Longitude points are within the region of 4 other specified ones. An application of this is specifying 4 intersections and seeing if the address is within that region. With the Google Maps Geocoding API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) it's easy to convert the intersections into the long/lat and if the area is a perfect rectangle it's easy.... but what if the street is curvey? Does something like this already exist?

Comment: There is a LatLngBounds class in the google maps api that has a method called 'contains', it can pass in a LatLng and will return true if it is within those bounds

Comment: LatLngBounds is rectangular, and I believe that questioner was asking about what to do if the four points described a quadrilateral that was not rectangular.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a point-in-polygon routine.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

There are many implementations of point-in-polygon; if you are using PostGIS for your a database backend, use the ST_Intersects.   There is already a question/answer on stackoverflow with code for a point-in-polygon function, see [Point in Polygon Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm)