# Suggested pointInPolygon algorithm works counterclockwise only

Tags: c#, computational-geometry, point-in-polygon

Once I tested the algorithm explained
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/7744339) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599478/7744339), I was as excited as the comments below it.

But after my test cases failed then a lot of debugging and tracing, that I realized it has a condition for it to work properly.

This algorithm needs the polygon `List<Point>` to have its' points sorted counterclockwise, otherwise the output is incorrect.

This is a very simple test case to validate my claim :

(You can use [this](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/SimplePlot/) to plot and test)

Polygon: Points sorted counterclockwise.

```
inputPoints.Add(new Point(1, 3));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(2, 1));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(6, 2));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(3, 6));
```

Test points:

```
Point testP1 = new Point(3, 3); //inside,  algorithm output :correct
Point testP2 = new Point(6, 3); //outside, algorithm output :correct
Point testP3 = new Point(9, 9); //outside, algorithm output :correct
```

Polygon: Points sorted clockwise.

```
inputPoints.Add(new Point(1, 3));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(2, 1));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(6, 2));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(3, 6));
```

Test points:

```
Point testP1 = new Point(3, 3); //inside,  algorithm output :correct
Point testP2 = new Point(6, 3); //outside, algorithm output :wrong answer
Point testP3 = new Point(9, 9); //outside, algorithm output :correct
```

Polygon: Points in random order (they're only 4 points, but when scaled, will result incorrect as well).

```
inputPoints.Add(new Point(2, 1));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(6, 2));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(1, 3));
inputPoints.Add(new Point(3, 6));
```

Test points:

```
 Point testP1 = new Point(3, 3); //inside,  algorithm output :wrong answer
 Point testP2 = new Point(6, 3); //outside, algorithm output :correct
 Point testP3 = new Point(9, 9); //outside, algorithm output :correct
```

Comment: You can't have a polygon "in random order" and expect which points are inside it to be constant, even with an algorithm that doesn't expect a particular direction. A bow-tie is not the same as a square.

Comment: @JonHanna its not a polygon in random order, its a set of points that can construct a polygon, and they could be randomly input.

Comment: That's your bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard concept with geometry and point in polygon algorithms from my own experience.

For example, even the SQL Server Spatial libraries have a function to ensure that the GEOMETRY imported is oriented correctly to work with their functions.

SQL Server Spatial `ReorientObject(geography)` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929311.aspx